# Stereo convolution with web audio

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to convolve a mono impulse with a stereo audio file using the web audio api. The problem is instead of getting true stereo output, I'm getting what looks and sounds like the same track duplicated to both channels. Here's my code:

```
var context = new AudioContext();

var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = BUFFERS.user; // stereo file

var splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2);

var convolverL = context.createConvolver();
    convolverL.normalize = false;
    convolverL.buffer = BUFFERS.impulse; // mono impulse

var convolverR = context.createConvolver();
    convolverR.normalize = false;
    convolverR.buffer = BUFFERS.impulse; // same mono impulse

var merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);

var gain = context.createGain();
    gain.gain.value = 0.75;

// make connections
source.connect(splitter);

splitter.connect(convolverL, 0);
splitter.connect(convolverR, 1);

convolverL.connect(merger, 0, 0);
convolverR.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(gain);

gain.connect(context.destination);

source.start(0);
```

Comment: The syntax looks right, as long as the channels in your `BUFFERS.user` is encoded properly.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope. I have recently discovered web audio sometimes decides to change the sample rate of the original file when you use decodeAudioData, which could have something to do with it, but I didn't test it. The sample rate changing thing was kind of a deal breaker for me and web audio, so I wrote my own convolution script.

Comment: What browser do you use? Maybe problem there. What if connect true stereo source to one mono convolver?